# How many years have passed since the start of the current kalpa?

Tags: time, kalpa

The name of current kalpa is Swetha Varaha Kalpa.

How many years has been completed till now from the starting point of the Swetha Varaha Kalpa?

Answer (score 4):

Taking the units of time from [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuga), Let's try to calculate it.

Each Kalp has 14 Manwantara and 15 SandhiKal, and SandhiKal is only equal to a Satyug.
(The other answer here says there are 72 ChaturYug in one Manwantara, but as per [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuga) let's keep it to 71, it could be actually 72, let me know if I am mistaken.)

We are in 7th Manwantara, it means 7 SandhiKal (1,728,000 each) and 6 Manwantara(306,720,000 each) has passed

> 7 * 1,728,000 (SandhiKal) = 12,096,000
>
> 6 * 306,720,000 (Manwantara) = 1,840,320,000

And we are in 28th ChaturYug, it means 27 ChaturYug (4,320,000) already passed

> 27 * 4,320,000 = 116,640,000

and We are living in Kalyug, so other 3 are passed it gives

> 1,728,000 + 1,296,000, + 864,000 = 3,888,000

Now, Kalyug started on 18 February 3102 BCE, that gives

> 3102 + 2019 = 5121

Adding all the above we get

> 12,096,000 + 1,840,320,000 + 116,640,000 +  3,888,000 + 5121
>   = **1,972,949,121 years passed in this Kalp.**

Let me know if I missed something, 
and thanks for the question, I hadn't done so much maths for a long while.

Comment: How many human years left for Kaliyuga to end?

Comment: @salazarin one kalyug is 432,000 years and 5122 are passed, so the remaining time should be 426,878. Basically, too long to bother in our puny lifetime.

Comment: Lol yes! I asked this question because you must have heard of Bhrama Kumaris spiritual society. They claim the end of Kalyug is near and that Lord Vishnu has already taken birth. So I got confused so as to what is true

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a slightly different number. Manu Vivisvat came 120,531,102 BC. A Manvantara is 306,720,000 years. (6 x 306,720,000) + 120,531,102 BC = 1,960,851,102 BC. The Brahma Kumaris are not traditional Hindus. They have their own unique spiritual worldview. There is no imminent Hindu messiah, as Kalkin is over 400,000 years from coming.

Comment: A Manvantara is a left ambiguous amount more than 306,720,000 years. Also, the Buddha avatar makes more sense as future Buddha Maitreya, which incidentally means he comes before Kalkin, whenever that is.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).